# How can a Linux process report its own CPU usage

Tags: c, linux, time

I have a C program which I would like to report:

- its elapsed wall clock time (how long it has run for)
- userspace cpu time used (possibly more than wall clock time if multi-threaded and busy)
- kernel/iowait/etc time used

I can do this from outside, using the "time" command, but I need each child process to report its own usage.  "time" aggregates the parent and child processes, but I need a line per child process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like POSIX `times()` might be the answer.  I'll confirm if this is the correct answer, after testing tomorrow.

After further reading, `getrusage()` looked best:

```
struct rusage rusage = {0};
int ret = getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &rusage);
if (ret) {
    perror("worker_exit()");
    exit(errno);
}
double ru_utime = rusage.ru_utime.tv_sec + rusage.ru_utime.tv_usec / 1000000.0;
double ru_stime = rusage.ru_stime.tv_sec + rusage.ru_stime.tv_usec / 1000000.0;
```

Comment: See `wait4` and `clock_gettime`

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Thanks, I followed the the `wait4()` page to `getrusage()`.